# C# driver handling GUIDs

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Having some issues querying back from Mongo on Id when it's a guid. I have a really stupid test class, its just public Guid Id {get;set}. I create a collection and do an insert of this test class. In the shell i see it as

```
{ "_id" : BinData(3,"9q+FwoU/RE2+Iq3w7hK1JA==") }
```

I then try to do

```
var query = Query.EQ("Id", Id);
```

If I look in the debugger, it shows up as

```
{ "Id" : CSUUID("c285aff6-3f85-4d44-be22-adf0ee12b524") }
```

However, it doesn't return anything.. Am I missing something obvious here? Also, side note, the shell has no idea what CSUUID is.. is there a way to enable this? CentOS server if it matters...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Id` will automatically be mapped to the reserved primary key name `_id`. You should change your query to

```
Query.EQ("_id", Id)
```

This should fix your problem.

---

**Some Background about GUIDs**

That thing about `CSUUID` is good to know, however: it tells you the driver is using the legacy representation of GUIDs in the C# driver. I believe this is still the default, so no need to worry. There are different encodings because other languages or operating systems have different byte orders.

You can extend the shell to 'understand' different formats of GUIDs, a *very* helpful extension in any case for all kinds of debugging:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/uuidhelpers.js

This makes it easier to debug using the shell. Just download the js and start mongo using `mongo --shell uuidhelpers.js`.

Comment: To stop the driver from adding CSUUID, you can you pass the value in as a string rather than a GUID.

Comment: @Andrew: No, you can't. That will look for strings in the database, and `CSUUID(someString) != someString`. The same is true for `ObjectId`. Also, the strings will require considerably more storage than their byte representations. What's more is that the driver doesn't 'add' `CSUUID`. `CSUUID` is a js helper method that enables you to easily create the same binary representation that's used by C# from a string in JavaScript, hence the driver's `ToString()` method has an override so what's displayed in the debugger can be used to query the db from the command line.

Comment: I should clarify, I am using string representation for GUIDs in the database.